# Search results not efficient, php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, search

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.1; I have a search feature and results page. The results are very specific.

Example:
Product name: AD-45.
Typed into search query = yields lots of results.

AD45 yields no results...

How can i ignore "-" if the first result yields nothing, and ignore "/" if the first result yields nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['s'])) {
    die('You must define a search term!');
}

$highlight = true; //highlight results or not
$search_in = array('html', 'htm', 'php'); //allowable filetypes to search in
$search_dir = '..'; //starting directory
$recursive = true; //should it search recursively or not
define('SIDE_CHARS', 80);
$file_count = 0;
$search_term = mb_strtolower($_GET['s'], 'UTF-8');
//$search_term = $_GET['s'];
$search_term_length = strlen($search_term);
$final_result = array();

$files = list_files($search_dir);

foreach($files as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title); //getting page title
    if(preg_match("#\<body.*\>(.*)\<\/body\>#si", $contents, $body_content)) { //getting content only between <body></body> tags
        $clean_content = strip_tags($body_content[0]); //remove html tags
        $clean_content = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $clean_content); //remove duplicate whitespaces, carriage returns, tabs, etc
        //$found = strpos_recursive($clean_content, $search_term);
        $found = strpos_recursive(mb_strtolower($clean_content, 'UTF-8'), $search_term);
        $final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1];
        $final_result[$file_count]['file_name'][] = $file;
    }
    if($found && !empty($found)) {
        for($z = 0; $z < count($found[0]); $z++) {
            $pos = $found[0][$z][1];
            $side_chars = SIDE_CHARS;
            if($pos < SIDE_CHARS) {
                $side_chars = $pos;
                $pos_end = SIDE_CHARS + $search_term_length;
            } else {
                $pos_end = SIDE_CHARS * 2 + $search_term_length;
            }

            $pos_start = $pos - $side_chars;
            $str = substr($clean_content, $pos_start, $pos_end);
            $result = preg_replace('#' . $search_term . '#ui', '<span class="search">\0</span>', $str);
            //$result = preg_replace('#'.$search_term.'#ui', '<span class="search">'.$search_term.'</span>', $str);
            $final_result[$file_count]['search_result'][] = $result;
        }
    } else {
        $final_result[$file_count]['search_result'][] = '';
    }
    $file_count++;
}
?>
```

I have added this near the top as a workaround as my issue is really with part numbers, but I am not sure if I need it:

```
function str_insert($str, $search, $insert) {
    $index = strpos($str, $search);
    if($index === false) {
        return $str;
    }
    return substr_replace($str, $insert . $search, $index, strlen($search));
}
if(strpos($search_term, "-40") > -1 || strpos($search_term, "-45") > -1) {}
else { $search_term = str_insert($search_term, "4", "-"); }
```

Comment: Why strip those characters only if the first result yields nothing? I'd say your best bet would be stripping them always.

Comment: Please expand on your comment. If there is a better way to do this that yeilds better results and reduces code it sounds good to me.

Comment: I'm not saying it yields better results. Let me break it down: assuming your clients will put in a model number in perfectly and precisely is unreasonable. You could just strip such special characters altogether (before the line `$search_term = mb_strtolower($_GET['s'], 'UTF-8');`, do for example `$search_term = str_replace(array("-", "\"), "", $_GET['s']);`. I guess this should answer the "how to strip characters" portion of your question :)